gitignore file inside a folder and want to exclude a folder outside that
I have my current repo setup like below
project/
├── .cicd
├── .github
├── .idea
├── .primer
├── airflow/
└── module/
    └── .gitignore

I have my .gitignore file inside module folder.
Now, I want to exclude the .idea/ folder from committing.
How do I do that ?
my current .gitignore file:
.idea/
target


why do you have a .gitignore in the "module" directory? Can you have a .gitignore file in the root directory?

this is how it is, in my org project repo and i don't wan't to change that

You cannot ignore .idea/ from module/.gitignore. If you don't want to create a top-level .gitignore the only alternative is .git/info/exclude but please be advised — this is you personal file, you cannot commit it for everyone to use.

You can create a second .gitignore file at the root of your folder which includes .idea/. It might also be easier and cleaner to just include a single .gitignore file at the root of your project directory which includes not only .idea/ but also the paths of the files ignored inside the module/ directory, like so:
.idea/
module/file_to_ignore_1
modole/file_to_ignore_2


Just add this to .gitignore
.idea/

In case .idea/ was already tracked before, you need to remove it from the repo with command:
git rm -r --cached .idea


That will not work for the OP because they have .gitignore in a wrong place.

Really, I have tested it from my side and it work perfect

With .gitignore inside a subfolder?

yes, for sure. I created three folders module, .idea, .note, and put .gitignore into module with following command  .idea. When I push to repo, it only push the module and .note folder

Please put a file into .idea and show us the result of git status: echo test >.idea/test && git status

Hi @LocNguyen, I already have .idea/ added in my gitignore but when i try git status, it shows me .idea/ folder in untracked files. And when i do (git add . ) the .idea/ folder is added. I then write git restore --staged .idea/ to remove it before commit
